# Minimizing number of MxM squared tiles in an infinite grid covered by any part of a shape

Tags: tiling

Without restriction (e.g. continuity or convexity are not guaranteed), we're given an `W x H` raster-based shape that needs to be placed on an infinite tiling of `M x M` squares. The shape can placed at any integer positional offset within those squares.

The goal is to minimize the number of squares containing *any* part of that shape.

For example, this shape (shown in orange) can be placed in a way that occupies seven squares on a tiling of `10 x 10`:
[image]

However, a more optimal placement is an offset of (+2, 0) which occupies six squares by leaving the central bottom square unoccupied:

[image]

Can the brute-force solution (`O(W * H * M * M)`) be improved upon? How / why not?

Comment: I don't have time to write full solution, so that's the idea for $O(WH)$. For offset $(0,0)$: 1) for each $M\times M$ square, compute the number of colored pixels in it 2) for each row and column in each square, compute the number of colored pixels in it (there are $M$ rows and columns in each square). Consider offsets $(0,0),(0,1),\ldots,(0,M)$. When you go from offset $(0,i)$ to $(0,i+1)$, only one row changes in each square. And since for each row the number of pixels is precomputed, update can be done in $O(1)$ per square. There are $HW/M^2$ squares and $M^2$ offsets, giving $O(HW)$ time.

Comment: I don't believe that solution accounts for diagonal moves correctly, since the row and column offset data isn't sufficient to avoid double counting during moves on both axes

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Right. That does not seem to be clear for me as well. However, Dmitry's algorithm does give $O(HWM)$ complexity, if executed for offsets $(0,0)$, $(1,0), \dotsc,(M,0)$, and moving row-wise for each one?

Comment: When you go from $(i,0)$ to $(i+1,0)$, you have to update $O(1)$ pixels per column. There are $O(HW/M)$ columns and $O(M)$ such shifts, giving $O(HW)$ overall. So you start with $(i,0)$ for all $i$ and compute answer for $(i,0), ..., (i,M)$ as in the previous comment.

Comment: @Dmitry When you go from $(i,0)$ to $(i+1,0)$, you need to change row info also. That would not be $O(1)$ time. That is what Ryan meant.

Comment: `I don't believe that solution accounts for diagonal moves` If there are *moves* to be taken account of, *the questions* needs to state that.

Comment: @greybeard It's entirely implied. I wrote "placed at any integer positional offset within those squares", not "any integer offset along either axis". Why would the brute-force solution be `O(W * H * M * M)` if diagonal moves weren't allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an algorithm. The TL;DR is that we can efficiently precompute a parallel image that indicates whether each position in the image contains any occupied pixels if we were to start a subgrid at that position (going down and to the right, chosen arbitrarily), and determining which collection of those positions produces the minimum total number of occupied subgrids can then be done in simple iteration.

- Compute a "row occupancy" grid which extends to the "left" of the image by M additional pixels. Each pixel in this grid is TRUE if any pixel within M pixels to the right of it (including itself) is nonempty. This can be done in `O(HW)` time because you can iterate each row backwards, keeping track of how long it's been since the last time you saw an occupied pixel
- Compute a "grid occupancy" grid, which is computed similarly. This grid extends "above" the top of the image by M additional pixels as well as to the left by M additional pixels. The algorithm is the same as the prior step, except applied to the row occupancy grid - count from the bottom up, keeping track of the last time you saw an occupied row, marking TRUE when the last occupied row was within the last M pixels.

The grid-occupancy-grid now contains a TRUE if any pixels are present in the square extending down and to the right by M pixels. With this grid, you can iterate through all possible `M x M` offsets, summing up how many TRUE pixels are at `(x + M * N, y + M * N)`, for all legal `N`. This final pass visits each pixel in the grid-occupancy-grid exactly once, so the overall runtime is `O((H + M) * (W + M))`